# CCTMXTiledMap (Cocos2d-x) Error on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

guys
I tried putting this into the code but no success

```
CCTMXTiledMap* map = CCTMXTiledMap::tiledMapWithTMXFile("TileMaps/orthogonal-test2.tmx");
```

I have the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cocos2d::CCTMXTiledMap * __cdecl cocos2d::CCTMXTiledMap::tiledMapWithTMXFile(char const *)"
```

Can someone offer me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: the error tells you the code for that function isn't available. Either the source (implementation) file for CCTMXT... is missing from your project, or it's not available  on the windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem when I test the tile map with Hello World project. The author maybe forgot including all source code into that project. And the error happens because missing CPP files for tile map. To solve this, add all files under the folder "cocos2dx/tileMap_parallax_nodes" into current project.

http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/23325?r=34274

Screen shot:
[http://cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2363/Screenshot%20(3).png](http://cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2363/Screenshot%20%283%29.png)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error, because my project miss the source (implementation) file for CCTMXT...

Answer (score 0):

Guys its not working in cocos2d-x version 3.3 its working in v3.2
Check out, It will run in windows phone. I got the output
add `tmx` file in assets folder in visual studio

```
TMXTiledMap* platform = TMXTiledMap::create("Tile.tmx");
    addChild(platform);
```